# How should I use a decimal point in calculate app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a calculation application.
Somehow, I could make buttons 0〜9 and four operations(+, -, *, ÷) as I imagined.
Then, I would like to add a decimal point button.
But, I am not sure how to add the button and connected with 0〜9 buttons.
Could you please give me advice.

below is the 1 button as reference.

```
- (void) createButton1{
    self.button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.button1.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 330.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);//20.0f
    [self.button1 setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(sendOne) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.button1];
}

 - (void) sendOne{
    NSLog(@"ステータスは%d",state);
    NSLog(@"sendOne before");
    EnterNumber = EnterNumber * 10 + 1;
    DisplayNumber = EnterNumber;
    labelTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", DisplayNumber];
    NSLog(@"%.1f",firstNumber);
    NSLog(@"%.1f",secondNumber);
    state = 0;
}
```

Comment: the concept looks a bit a wrong, you might use _string_ to store the typed input instead, and when it needs to be used for the calculation you can convert it to real number.

Comment: What exactly is your problem. As I see it, there should not be any issue with the '.'. Make Sure `EnterNumber` is not an integer, but a `double`/`float`. Also, Use strings for displaying, until you actually have to perform calculations.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer, his problem is that formula (`EnterNumber * 10 + 1`) is not valid after a decimal point is typed.

Comment: True, silly of me to miss that.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will use holex's advise at first, thank you.